# Make Delphi TList immutable

Tags: delphi, immutability, delphi-xe4, tlist

is it possible to make a Delphi TList immutable? 
I searched in the delphi doc for a class similar to the unmodifiableList in java, but didn't found anything.

regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Delphi RTL contains no classes that implement immutable or read-only lists. You will have to implement such a class yourself, or find a library that offers such functionality.

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `IReadOnlyList<T>` from Spring4D.

If you have an `IList<T>` you just call `AsReadOnlyList` (`AsReadOnly` since 2.0) and it returns you the same instance as `IReadOnlyList<T>` which does not provide methods to manipulate the list (no `Add`, `Delete` or setter for the `Items` property).

However there is a difference to the `unmodifiableList` from Java:

In Java you really get a `List<T>` which will throw `UnsupportedOperationException` when you try to modify it while in Spring4D which is mostly modeled after .NET you get something that you cannot call any modifying operations on.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple Generic immutable list implementation with Map & Filter support :

```
unit Immutable;

interface

uses
   System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TFilter<TItem> = reference to function(AItem: TItem): Boolean;
  TMapper<TItem> = reference to function(AItem: TItem): TItem;

  IImmutableList<TItem> = interface
    function Insert(Index: Integer; AItem: TItem): IImmutableList<TItem> ;
    function Filter(AFilter: TFilter<TItem>): IImmutableList<TItem> ;
    function Map(AMapper: TMapper<TItem>): IImmutableList<TItem> ;

    function GetEnumerator: TEnumerator<TItem>;
  end;


  TImmutableList<TItem> = class(TInterfacedObject, IImmutableList<TItem>)
  private
    FList: TList<TItem>;
  public
    constructor Create(); overload;
    constructor Create(AImmutableList: IImmutableList<TItem>); overload;
    destructor  Destroy; override;

    function Insert(Index: Integer; AItem: TItem): IImmutableList<TItem>;
    function Filter(AFilter: TFilter<TItem>): IImmutableList<TItem>;
    function Map(AMapper: TMapper<TItem>): IImmutableList<TItem>;

    function GetEnumerator: TEnumerator<TItem>;
  end;

implementation

{ TImmutableList<TItem> }

constructor TImmutableList<TItem>.Create;
begin
  FList := TList<TItem>.Create;
end;

constructor TImmutableList<TItem>.Create(AImmutableList: IImmutableList<TItem>);
var
  AItem : TItem;
begin
  FList := TList<TItem>.Create;
  for AItem in AImmutableList do
    FList.Add(AItem);
end;

destructor TImmutableList<TItem>.Destroy;
begin
  FList.Free;
  inherited;
end;

function TImmutableList<TItem>.GetEnumerator: TEnumerator<TItem>;
begin
  Result := FList.GetEnumerator;
end;

function TImmutableList<TItem>.Insert(Index: Integer; AItem: TItem): IImmutableList<TItem>;
var
  NewList :  TImmutableList<TItem>;
begin
  NewList := TImmutableList<TItem>.Create(Self);
  TImmutableList<TItem>(NewList).FList.Insert(Index, AItem);
  Result := NewList;
end;

function TImmutableList<TItem>.Filter(AFilter: TFilter<TItem>): IImmutableList<TItem>;
var
  AItem : TItem;
  NewList : TImmutableList<TItem>;
begin
  NewList := TImmutableList<TItem>.Create();
  for AItem in FList do begin
    if AFilter(AItem) then
      TImmutableList<TItem>(NewList).FList.Add(AItem)
  end;
  Result := NewList;
end;

function TImmutableList<TItem>.Map(AMapper: TMapper<TItem>): IImmutableList<TItem>;
var
  AItem : TItem;
  NewList : TImmutableList<TItem>;
begin
  NewList := TImmutableList<TItem>.Create();
  for AItem in FList do begin
      TImmutableList<TItem>(NewList).FList.Add( AMapper(AItem))
  end;
  Result := NewList;
end;
end.
```

I'm using it in https://github.com/pierrejean-coudert/ReduxDelphi TodoMVC sample code.